# Custom Authentication Helper class. Need help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have helper method which is only checking if User is Authenticated but its generating error

**Helper method**

```
public static bool IsLoggedIn(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

**View**

```
@if (GH.IsLoggedIn) //Error is on this line
{ 
    <div class="sign-text" >Signed In As @GH.IdentityName </div>
}
```

**Error**

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'IsLoggedIn' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

Anyone tell me whats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why woudn't you call it like this `@if (Html.IsLoggedIn()) { .. }`

...

You may want to make this method render appropriate HTML instead of doing `@if (...)` check in your view.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SignInText(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    // you code here
}
```

Then insert it into your view this way:

```
@Html.SignInText()
```

Comment: Thanks my stupidity . Can you tell me how to write this Ternary statement please @Html.IsLoggedIn() ? <div class="sign-text" >Signed In As @Html.IdentityName </div>

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Html.IsLoggedIn() ? "<div class=\"sign-text\">Signed In as " + Html.Encode(Html.IdentityName) + "</div>" : String.Empty)`

Comment: Do you want me to use above Singin link in HtmlHelp of yours SignInText. Hiding logic from view?